# Connection error to h2 database: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length string

Tags: h2

I am using the console

For the url:  jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:/shared/test

General error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length string" [50000-180] HY000/50000 (Help)

It seems that the h2 url has changed in latest version. What is the correct way to create a path to /shared/test ?

**UPDATE**  When attempting the URL without colon we get the following:

```
val url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/shared/test;auto_server=true"

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/shared/test;auto_server=true". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-180]
```

Comment: No, the URL didn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a colon after `localhost`, but no port number. You need to either use:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/shared/test
```

or

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9123/shared/test
```

**Update**

The next question is about the database URL `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/shared/test;auto_server=true`. This is a relative path, as the exceptions says. You can read [the docs for this error message](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c90011). I think what you want to use is:

(Windows):

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:/shared/test;auto_server=true
```

or (Linux, Mac OS: root directory):

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost//shared/test;auto_server=true
```

or (relative to the current user home directory):

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/shared/test;auto_server=true
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Before I ever put a colon in there, I had tried it like you show above. It repeatedly gave an error, and I have updated the OP with the specifics.

Comment: I have shown the error for following your example without the colon.

Comment: The remaining issue is that you are using a relative path. I have updated my answer, please read it again. Most likely the solution for you is to use `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost//shared/test;auto_server=true` (two slashes after `localhost`).